# Mostrar mensagem de erro quando ModelState não for válido

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quando faço a submissão do form ele reconhece que o `ModelState.Valid` é invalido porém quando ele retorna a `View()` não mostra as mensagens de erro que coloquei na `Model`.

Minha Controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Cadastrar(ProdutoCreateModel produtoCreateModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                  //se a model for valida salvar informações
                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Produto");
            }
            return View(produtoCreateModel);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Produto");
        }
    }
```

Parte da minha View :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Cadastrar", "Produto",
                                                new AjaxOptions
                                                {
                                                    HttpMethod = "Post"
                                                }))
                {
                    //Valida o Formulario enviado
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                        <div style="text-align: center">
                            <input id="imagem" name="imagem" type="file" class="file-loading">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control " })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodigoProduto)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CodigoProduto, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoProduto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrecoPromocional)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrecoPromocional, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatalogoId)
                            @Html.DropDownList("DropDown", new SelectList(ViewBag.Catalogo, "CatalogoId", "Nome"), "Selecione a categoria", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" style="margin:0 auto" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                }
```

Annotations na minha Model :

```
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do produto")]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
```

Pelo que andei lendo esta seria a forma de fazer, porém quando retorna para a view, nenhuma mensagem é mostrada.

Estou usando `@Ajax.BeginForm`, para submeter o formulário.

Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: William, teria como postar o corpo inteiro do formulário?

Comment: Sim, um momento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do @Leonardo Bonneti, você deve chamar a validação do unobitrusive, pois quando vc usar @Ajax, você deve recarregar as funções js que você necessita.

Exemplo:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Action1",
    "Controller",
    null,
    new AjaxOptions { 
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
        UpdateTargetId = "result"
    },
    null)
)
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

var onSuccess = function(result) {
    // enable unobtrusive validation for the contents
    // that was injected into the <div id="result"></div> node
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(result));
};
```

Comment: Muito interessante, vou tentar aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, por eliminação acredito que o seu problema seja a ativação do `ValidationSummary`, pois o seu model está ok, controller ok o que faltou essa linha dentro do seu `form`.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Você pode colocar embaixo de `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

Comment: Eu adicionei essa linha de código mas não funcionou, eu troquei de `@Ajax.BeginForm` para `@Html.BeginForm` e funcionou, acho que foi um mal entendimento da funcionalidades desses métodos.

Comment: Eu imaginei isso, mas como `@Ajax.BeginForm` é um metodo do próprio MVC achei que funcionaria, de qq forma boa. O `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` resolveu? dps da uma olhada se funciona sem ele só para tirar duvida.